# Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{getButtonText()}} - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam getting the following error when I calling a function

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{getButtonText()}} 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7BgetButtonTex…%A0&p1=TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20'length'%20of%20undefined
    at angular.js:78
    at Object.$get.fn (angular.js:8139)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:11528)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:11774)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js:164)
    at HTMLDocument.n.event.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.n.event.add.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9193
```

The same code is working for other pages, but not working for this page.

**HTML Code:**

```
<td>
<span>
    <img src="images/note.png" class="imgComment" ng-mouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'"
    ng-mouseleave="this.style.cursor='auto'" style="width:30px"
    ng-click="edit({{item.userId}})"></img>
</span>
</td>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.edit = function(recordId) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'editView.html',
            controller: 'EditController',
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                recordId: function() {
                    return recordId;
                },
                resourceName: function() {
                    return $scope.resourceName;
                },
                deptId : function () {
                    return $scope.dept;
                }
            }
        });
```

Any idea about what might be causing the error?

Comment: use this `ng-click="edit(item.userId)"` instead of  `ng-click="edit({{item.userId}})"`. Let me know it works nor not??

Comment: `getButtonText()` isn't actually in any of the code you shared with us.

Comment: @Roy.23, getting same error

Comment: @J4G. Even I don't have getButtonText() in my code

Comment: @Roy.23 error is from `getButtonText()` but OP does not share it yet.

Comment: Do you have `$cope` somewhere in your code instead of `$scope`?

Comment: @trincot no, I don't have $cope in my code.

Comment: https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/22  got the solution here.

Comment: You could type this as a response to your own question and accept the answer, that way this question is no longer considered unresolved. Thanks.